# UX Brighton event about prototyping

Tags: discussion, promotion, conference

Next week I'll be speaking at a small [UX Brighton get together about "practical prototyping"](http://uxbrighton.org.uk/practical-prototyping/) along with a few other people. Our talk is focused on our product, Handcraft, and how it relates to HTML prototyping, but there are some other speakers who will cover prototyping with other tools like Fireworks, Ethnio, and some people sharing their experiences with the prototyping process.

Just wanted to let you guys know in case there's anyone in the area who'd like to attend. Jin's providing me with a moderator's business card and some flyers to hand out so we can spread the word a bit about UX StackExchange there as well.

Comment: fantastic! I would say "send some UX shirts", but UX is in a bit of an in-between state since it has a final design, but is not technically a launched site yet...

Answer (score 2):

Harry Brignull gave a quick mention of UX.SE at the end of the talks and afterwards in the pub I spammed people with business cards. They all seemed interested in it, if a bit confused that I was handing out some business card that had nothing to do with Handcraft (some even said "can I just have the one for your product?" which is definitely not what I expected ;-)).

So I guess we'll see if people start showing up!

Oh and I dropped a stack off with Danny Hope (the UXBri organiser, @yandle) and Nate Bolt (@boltron), who might both be able to give them out if they meet people who could use them.

Comment: Great! I hope you had fun!